# convert list to sequence of tuples

Tags: python, list, sequence

Is there anyway to convert

```
A = [((0,0,0),), ((1,1,1),), ((2,2,2),) ]
```

to this

```
B = ((0,0,0),), ((1,1,1),), ((2,2,2),)
```

In other words, all I want to do is remove the end brackets so that I can input B into a certain argument.  I do not want any outer parentheses/brackets/quotations on B

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with `B`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing `A` as an argument to a function `fn(A1, A2, A3)`, you can pass the elements of `A` individually as follows:

```
fn( *A )
```

The `*` operation on a list/tuple when passed to a function *unpacks* the elements in the list/tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a string representation:

```
B = ", ".join(repr(t) for t in A)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to do it would be to do something like this:

```
B = A[0], A[1], A[2]
```

Which results in

```
(((0, 0, 0),), ((1, 1, 1),), ((2, 2, 2),))
```